# Calculate rarity of multi-label data in Pandas data frame and create sample_weights respective to occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm trying to create a sample_weights Series to add to my `y` dataframe, with respect to how rarely that particular row happens.

My `y` matrix is multi-label binary encoded like so:

```
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

What I need to do is create a `sample_weights` Series where the more rare a given label is, the higher the weight is. So, for the above toy data set, `sample_weights` should look something roughly like:

```
3
2
3
3
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Where the more common rows are weighted less and the more uncommon rows are weighted more, relative to how often they occur.

I'm looking to create (from the Keras docs):

> **sample_weight**: Numpy array of weights for the training samples, used for scaling the loss function (during training only). Pass a flat (1D) Numpy array with the same length as the input samples (1:1 mapping between weights and samples)

EDIT: Added Keras docs for reference, and clarified weighting strategy

Comment: I got this far: `df_y_count = df_y.groupby(labels).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})['count']*-0.25` which is close, but I'm sure there's a smarter mathematical solution

Comment: Never mind, the above comment does not help, it creates an array of the wrong length, although it does count unique instances correctly there's no way to then attach those unique instance counts to the original `y`

Comment: If I take each row to be a label, this is the frequency in which they occur `[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`  The last 6 rows each happen with the same frequency.  That means I can not reconcile with your sample output.  Please clarify what is a label and how to distinguish one from another.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you for your response! The point is to apply larger weights to rarer labels. I said "roughly" in my original post, because the fake weights I wrote into the example are I'm sure not proportional.

Comment: Yes, but I'm still left wondering and guessing at what you mean... and I don't want to guess.  I suspect that others don't want to either.

Comment: Ok @piRSquared, I updated the fake weights to match your suggestion. Also added Keras docs in case it's still confusing. Thank you for your help